# Launch another app but not new process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So i found

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

But, then i want to close app which started it (it's needed for me to launcher connect to server, launch game and close itself) so it doesn't work.
My app:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Process.Start("xnagame.exe", "12345678");
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Also, what exactly "doesn't work"? What happens and what do you want instead?

Comment: Perhaps "doesn't work" means the code does not compile :)

Comment: This code doesn't make sense: it is a class definition but no method (or constructor) to hold the code. This should not compile!

Comment: Neither the question nor the provided code make sense... it's hard to make a reasonable answer out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the process so you have a handle to close it.  Not all processes close gracefully.

```
     try
     {
        Process myProcess;
        myProcess = Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
        // Display physical memory usage 5 times at intervals of 2 seconds.
        for (int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
        {
           if (!myProcess.HasExited)
           {
               // Discard cached information about the process.
               myProcess.Refresh();
               // Print working set to console.
               Console.WriteLine("Physical Memory Usage: " 
                                    + myProcess.WorkingSet.ToString());
               // Wait 2 seconds.
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
           }
           else {
               break;
           } 
        }

        // Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
        myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
        // Free resources associated with process.
        myProcess.Close();

     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("The following exception was raised: ");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
```

Comment: Uhm, I think the OP want to close the app that launch the process, not the process launched

Comment: @Steve OK, I think I agree your interpretation.  But it is not clear.  I will leave it up for a day.

Comment: Sory for misunderstood. This is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` overload, and set the `UseShellExecute` property to `true`.